# What are the pros and cons of using AWS AppSync vs Firestore for scalable chat application?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, chat, scalability, aws-appsync

I am planning to develop a scalable chat application as a part of a project, project is mobile app hoping to expand to the web. I came to consider the following options

- [AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/)
- [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/)

Currently I am using Firebase in my mobile app for other things (authentication and etc).

**My findings :**

- Firebase documentation is super friendly and easy to get started with
  less time.
- According to my calculations using Firestore seems cheaper than AppSync (cost
  of AppSync + DynamoDB vs cost of Firestore)
- There are certain limits in Firestore according to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).
- AppSync is uses GraphQL so have more granular access to data.

I searched for comparison between AppSync and Cloud Firestore but did not find any good in-depth comparison.

**What are the pros and cons of using AWS AppSync vs Firestore for scalable chat application?**